# Did Archimedes have any students?

Tags: ancient-rome, ancient-greece, science, philosophy, engineering

We know that Archimedes learnt a lot from his father, Phidias (who was an astronomer) and most likely studied in Alexandria, alongside other great contemporaries such as Eratosthenes of Cyrene and Conon of Samos, with whom he would have collaborated and corresponded with about his work.

Do we however know at all whether Archimedes had any students that he would have taught personally?

Comment: The short answer: this is not known, and unlikely. And probably will never be known for sure.

Comment: You might get a better answer in the "History of science and mathematics" forum.

Comment: I do not think so, as far as I can see, History of science and mathematics is more about the development of scientific and mathematical concepts than about particular historical events or lives

Comment: @Alex why do you think it is unlikely? Many philosophers in ancient Greece had students - Socrates had Xenophon and Plato to name a few, Plato had Aristotle and the list goes on...

Comment: @michal Paszkiewicz: Why it is unlikely is explained in the answer of moudiz. Because there is no trace of any of them in the surviving literature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friend of his named Heracleides wrote a biography, but it was lost so the details of his biography is unknown.

But after reading its biography, (in my opinion ) I don't think he had any students. The quote below is from wikipedia

> Unlike his inventions, the mathematical writings of Archimedes were little known in antiquity. Mathematicians from Alexandria read
>   and quoted him, but the first comprehensive compilation was not made
>   until c. 530 AD by Isidore of Miletus in Byzantine Constantinople,
>   while commentaries on the works of Archimedes written by Eutocius in
>   the sixth century AD opened them to wider readership for the first
>   time.

I guess if he had any students, they would help more to spread his mathematical writings or

> General Marcellus was reportedly angered by the death of Archimedes,
>   as he considered him a valuable scientific asset and had ordered that
>   he not be harmed.[11] Marcellus called Archimedes "a geometrical
>   Briareus".

I guess If there are any students, I guess the general would ask for them or maybe there was a war the students had to participate in the war.

As a conclusion, because the there isn't a biography (and some assumptions I made above), it is hardly likely that he had any students.

Comment: This is pure guess work.

Comment: @fdb the answer is based on a fact and analysis , the fact is there is no biography for him as described in wikipedia so its hardly to know that , and as an analysis from his history there is no students mentioned

Answer (score 1):

It is, at this point in time, unknown as to whether Archimedes had any students or ran a school-(similar to Aristotle's Lyceum or Plato's Academy).  If I was to provide an educated guess-(based upon the little that I know regarding Archimedes' biography), I would say......probably not.  By today's standards, Archimedes would have been a professional Scientist and Inventor similar to someone, such as Thomas Edison.  Due to his plethora of inventions and mathematically oriented writings, I am not sure Archimedes would have had the time to teach! He may have had his own version of Teaching or Research Assistants-(similar to Aristotle's Lyceum), though, based on our current evidence, it seems to have been unlikely.

However, I don't think it's an impossibility that Archimedes may have had a school or a group of students in Siracusa, Sicily or that perhaps Archimedes may have had the ancient equivalent of a Visiting Professorship or Teaching Fellowship at The Alexandrian University in Egypt.  Many of the major Greek Scientific and Philosophical Thinkers dating back to Thales-(The Father of Western Science and Philosophy), were also Teachers and Educators.  Democritus, Pythagoras, Zeno, Heraclitus, Socrates, Hippocrates, Plato, Aristotle, Epicurus and Hypatia, were all professional Teachers and Educators, while also pursuing scientific and/or philosophical writings and research. So it is not necessarily an impossibility for Archimedes to have been part of the centuries long Ancient Greek intellectual tradition.

However, at this point in time, there is just no primary evidence which supports such a theoretical or circumstantial claim and therefore, it continues to remain unknown.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, it's an informative assessment, but generally it's good to include some sources with an answer.